# How to fecth ID property of LI element under a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am new to CSS and JQUERY. I want to get all the ids of the LI elements in string under in a JS file to parse further.

```
<div id="editSortable"> 
    <ul class="sortable-list  ui-sortable">
        <li id="TEXT_1">Test 1</li>
        <li id="TEXT_2">Test 2</li>
        <li id="TEXT_3">Test 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried below solution but its returning the object and not able to convert it into String

```
var columns = [];
$(#editSortable+ ' ul.sortable-list').each(function(){
    columns.push($(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));                
});
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: using this: `$('#editSortable > ul.sortable-list > li').each()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var columns = [];
$('#editSortable .sortable-list li').each((i, li)  => columns.push(li.id))

console.log(columns)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editSortable"> 
    <ul class="sortable-list  ui-sortable">
        <li id="TEXT_1">Test 1</li>
        <li id="TEXT_2">Test 2</li>
        <li id="TEXT_3">Test 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```